# converting all elements of an RDD[string] to float in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert all the values of RDD[string] to float

The RDD contains data similar to this

15.994

1.008

4.9594

an so on

RDD is in RDD[string] format.

I need to calculate the sum of all these values and hence need to convert them into float.

I found a code for this problem in python, but I need it in scala

python code :

```
     val massData1 = [map(float,i) for i in massData]
```

massData is the RDD[string]

Can anyone please tell me how I can add all the values in the RDD [string] by converting them into float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an strRDD which contains string, do transform as below:

```
val doubleRDD = strRDD.map(_.toFloat)
```

Then add them up:

```
val result = doubleRDD.reduce(_ + _)
```